# Rank of matrix whose coefficients are $a_{i,j}=\gcd(i,j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What are he possible methods for showing that the $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ whose coefficients are given by $a_{i,j}=\gcd(i,j)$ is inversible?